# Selected Options disappear in a multiple drop-down select tag with scroll bar in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following multiple drop down select tag

```css
.Something {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 16%;
}
```

```html
<select multiple size="5" class="Something">
  <option>Optionfghfghfgdgdffyuujkyujg 1</option>
  <option>Optionfghfghfgdgdffyuujkyujg 1</option>
  <option>Option n fgnfn ghdnghd ngdh 2</option>
  <option>Optionfghfghfgdgdffyuujkyujg 1</option>
  <option>Option n fgnfn ghdnghd ngdh 2</option>
  <option>Option n fgnfn ghdnghd ngdh 2</option>
</select>
```

So whenever I select an option the text towards the right of it disappears.

Like this

[image]

I have such several drop downs in my web portal. I don't want the option text to disappear. Can this be done using HTML or CSS rather than writing a customized JavaScript code? If so how?

Comment: No need for screen shots and Fiddles, when you can post a running version of your code right here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: Thanks scott. I didn't know that.

Comment: Yes, you may have images - it helps show the issue. Also JSFiddle may allow more stuff than the snippets here, be do post the code in a snippet too. @ScottMarcus - come on

Comment: In this case JSFiddle doesn't add any value and simply running the snippet shows the visual.

Comment: It shows the visual if you have the same browser as OP so an image is a great idea

Comment: Just as a note: This doesn't work in Firefox - the horizontal scrollbar won't render.

Comment: Thanks to both of you mplungjan and @ScottMarcus . I'm new to stack overflow. I think this information will help me for my next question.

Comment: @Sreekhar you seem to don't know you can edit your question

Comment: I know that, but I don't know how to write a question. I'm new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Horizontal scrolling for `<select>` elements is buggy in Edge/Chrome, and completely unsupported in Firefox.

A work-around supported *all* browsers would be to simply wrap it in a `<div>` and apply some of your CSS there instead:

```css
.Something {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
}

.Something > select {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="Something">
    <select multiple size="6">
      <option>Optionfghfghfgdgdffyuujkyujg 1</option>
      <option>Optionfghfghfgdgdffyuujkyujg 1</option>
      <option>Option n fgnfn ghdnghd ngdh 2</option>
      <option>Optionfghfghfgdgdffyuujkyujg 1</option>
      <option>Option n fgnfn ghdnghd ngdh 2</option>
      <option>Option n fgnfn ghdnghd ngdh 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Some changes had to be made for this to work. The `size` attribute of your `<select>` must match the number of options, and your `<div>` must have a set height.

Comment: Thanks @Santi I didn't know that.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why it does that, I can reproduce in Chrome.

This seems to fix it. Setting `float: left; min-width: 100%;` on the `<option>` element style.

`float: left` destroys the default block formatting context behaviour of the `<option>` tags in the `<select>`. `min-width: 100%` just makes it a little more aesthetically pleasing, it ensures that even the `<option>` tags which have content shorter than the width of the `<select>` are "fully highlighted" when selected.

P.S. This fixes the issue for Chrome and IE11, won't fix it for IE10- and Firefox as they don't support horizontal scrolling on a `<select>` element at all :)

```css
.Something {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 16%;
}

option {
  float: left;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<select multiple size="5" class="Something">
  <option>Optionfghfghfgdgdffyuujkyujg 1</option>
  <option>Optionfghfghfgdgdffyuujkyujg 1</option>
  <option>Option n fgnfn ghdnghd ngdh 2</option>
  <option>Optionfghfghfgdgdffyuujkyujg 1</option>
  <option>Option n fgnfn ghdnghd ngdh 2</option>
  <option>Option n fgnfn ghdnghd ngdh 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Nice simple solution! The selected option element takes the width of the select element, so cuts off anything outside that width. Unless there is a way to know the 'width' of the word because if you set width of the option to at least its full length you can see it all... this is probably the best way to go.

Comment: Yes, I was having an issue with Chrome. I think this works on all other select tags too. Thank you @Mathijs